# How can I compact this code? Too many if statements

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is there any way to compact this code I have? This is based on ASCII values and I'm trying to create a table for it. I can create a map which would probably be WAY simpler but I don't know if my professor is allowing that for some reason.

If I did do a map I'd just create one with all the standard ascii values rather than having all of these statements. But for the sake of this method I thought about implementing && and ! and || but dont know where to start.

```
void mark_cells(int row, int _table[][MAX_COLUMNS], const char columns[], int state) {
    if (columns == ALFA) {
        // A-Z
        for (int i = 65; i <= 90; ++i) {
            _table[row][i] = state;
        }
        // a-z
        for (int i = 97; i <= 122; ++i) {
            _table[row][i] = state;
        }
    }
    else if (columns == DIGITS) {
        // 0 - 9
        for (int i = 48; i <= 57; ++i) {
            _table[row][i] = state;
        }
    }
    else if (columns == OPERATORS) {
        // <, =, >
        for (int i = 60; i <= 62; ++i) {
            _table[row][i] = state;
        }
        // (,),*,+
        for (int i = 40; i <= 43; ++i) {
            _table[row][i] = state;
        }
        // {,|,}
        for (int i = 123; i <= 125; ++i) {
            _table[row][i] = state;
        }
        // !
        _table[row][33] = state;
        // %
        _table[row][37] = state;
        // &
        _table[row][38] = state;
        // -
        _table[row][45] = state;
    }
    else if (columns == SPACES) {
        _table[row][32] = state;
    }
    else if (columns == PUNC) {
        // ;
        _table[row][58] = state;
        // :
        _table[row][59] = state;
        // ?
        _table[row][63] = state;
        // '
        _table[row][39] = state;
        // .
        _table[row][46] = state;
        // ~
        _table[row][126] = state;
        // !
        _table[row][33] = state;
        // `
        _table[row][96] = state;
        // ,
        _table[row][44] = state;
        // -
        _table[row][45] = state;
    }
    
}
```

This code marks a row and column and sets it to a given state:
Here are my constants

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

const int MAX_COLUMNS = 256;
const int MAX_ROWS = 100;
const int MAX_BUFFER = 200;

const char ALFA[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const char DIGITS[] = "0123456789";
const char OPERATORS[] = "><=!+-%&|()*";
const char SPACES[] = {' ', '\t', '\n', '\0'};
const char PUNC[] = "?.,:;'`~!";
```

Comment: Not a good `switch` candidate, but `std::(unordered_)map<std::string, std::function<(prototype)>` might be a decent option. depends on use case.  Note comparing `char` arrays with `==` doesn't work unless you are deliberately comparing pointers. If you want to compare string values, you'll need `strcmp` or migrate to `std::string`.

Comment: There's no overlap I can see, so I think the map like you already suggested would be the best way to rewrite it.

Comment: as @user4581301 points out, having "columns" be an char[] is problematic. If you can make those an `enum` your map solution will be better.

Comment: Side note: `for (int i = 65; i <= 90; ++i)` might be more easily read with `for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; ++i)`

Comment: And if you can go with `enum`s `switch` is back on the table.

Comment: Apologies for not reading the question well enough to see that maps were banned.

Comment: it is unclear to me what this function is doing. I think probably the right thing is redesign the code that calls this function.

Comment: Is that function prototype `void mark_cells(int row, int _table[][MAX_COLUMNS], const char columns[], int state)` a requirement or it part of the homework and you can do it otherwise? Apart from storing mapping information or calling some other functions, that function would not change much...

Comment: *"Is there any way to compact this code I have?"* -- probably, but that is a lot of code to read through and interpret. Wouldn't it be kinder to your readers to write out in text what this function is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't know how this is supposed to work:

```
if (columns == ALFA)
```

If `columns` is of type `char[]`.  Is that a pointer comparison or a string comparison?  If the latter, it doesn't do what you think it will do (reliably).

If it's a string comparison, change `column` to be of type `const std::string&`.  Then those comparison to defined literals will work better.

For starters, have a helper function that does that loop that keeps repeating.

```
void setStateOnRange(int table[][MAX_COLUMNS], int row, int start, int end, int state) {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
            table[row][i] = state;
        }
}
```

Then your function becomes a lot easier to write:

```
void mark_cells(int row, int _table[][MAX_COLUMNS], const string& columns, int state) {
    if (columns == ALFA) {
        // A-Z
        setStateOnRange(_table, row, 'A','Z');
        setStateOnRange(_table, row, a','z');
    }
    else if (columns == DIGITS) {
        // 0 - 9
        setStateOnRange(_table, row, '0','9');
    }
    ...
```

Another idea is to have a static table that maps each ascii value to the column range you expect to have.  I'll let you intialize the table accordingly.  The implementation becomes really short.

```
void mark_cells(int row, int _table[][MAX_COLUMNS], const string& columns, int state) {

    static string columnmap[128] = {
           /* 0..31*/ NONE, NONE, NONE, ... <32 NONES in a row>,
           /* 32-47*/ SPACE, PUNC, PUNC, PUNC....
           /*48-57*/  DIGIT, DIGIT, DIGIT.... 
                      PUNC, PUNC, PUNC...
           /*65-90*/  ALFA, ALFA, etc....
           ...};

     for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
         if (columnmap[i] == columns) {
             table[row][i] = state;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just begin by making each group of characters a string.  For example:

```
const char* allAlpha = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
                       "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
const char* allDigits = "1234567890";
const char* allOperators = "<=>,*+!%&-";
...
```

Likewise for the others..  Then your logic would select one:

```
const char* selected = nullptr;
if (columns == ALFA)
    selected = allAlpha;
else if (columns == DIGITS)
    selected = allDigits;
else if (columns == OPERATORS)
    selected = allOperators;
...
```

Finally, if you selected something you can can walk through it to mark all these states:

```
if (selected)
{
    for (const char* p = selected; *p != '\0'; ++p)
        _table[row][(unsigned char)*p] = state;
}
```